# How do I ask users to provide me link for their youtube videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube.net-api

Is their any good way to ask users to link their you tube videos to my site.

Currently I am doing this in below way,

I have a text area field and help page which asks users to copy the code from youtube site and  paste the iframe code in my text area. However this way of doing things I feel is not correct as there exists a risk that people might provide malicious scripts in the text area and I dont do any validation on that field since its optional field in my form.

Can someone suggest better way for implementing this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply accept the video ID number, and validate that it matches `^\d*$`.

You should then build the `<iframe>` tag yourself in your view.

Comment: from this url, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_r05bKcopU   you mean this is video id v=k_r05bKcopU and then create a iframe and then load the video ?

Comment: No; `v=` is the URL parameter name.  Other than that, yes; exactly.

Comment: If someone enters a URL or embed code, you should parse out the ID from it automatically.

Comment: ok k_r05bKcopU  is just the video id ? and iframe src will look something like below correct after getting id http://www.youtube.com/embed/k_r05bKcopU

Comment: Ok thanks I got it the logic. Will do it the same way.Thanks SLaks